# iterate list of list object -jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to send a list of instances which each object also contain list of other instances. So I wonder if it is possible to iterate through list of instance of a parent instance?

For example:

```
Class A 
List<B> list_b;
```

then in controller:

```
model.addAttribute("list_a", list_a)
```

In my jsp, I am trying to do

```
<c:forEach items="${list_a}" var="alist">
   <c:set value="${alist.list_b}" var="list_b" />

   <c:forEach items="${list_b}" var="blist">
       ${blist.name}
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Will the above valid? Well, I think it would be possible, but I have an error :

on this line: `<c:forEach items="${list_b}" var="blist">`
    Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in `<c:forEach>`

If the above code is not valid, which will be other way to achieve the goal? Or I should construct two model attributes for list_a and list_b?

Comment: What is type of `list_b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, remove the `<c:set>`:

```
<c:forEach items="${list_a}" var="alist">
    <c:forEach items="${alist.list_b}" var="blist">
       ${blist.name}
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```